Why test runner not working in Unity 6 like in older Versions?
I'm working on a Project in Unity 6 and the test Runner isn't working.
Unity 6 Version (6000.0.15f)
.asmdef File
{
"name": "PlayModeTests",
"rootNamespace": "",
"references": [
    "UnityEngine.TestRunner",
    "UnityEditor.TestRunner",
    "TestSceneScripts"
],
"includePlatforms": [],
"excludePlatforms": [],
"allowUnsafeCode": false,
"overrideReferences": true,
"precompiledReferences": [
    "nunit.framework.dll"
],
"autoReferenced": false,
"defineConstraints": [
    "UNITY_INCLUDE_TESTS"
],
"versionDefines": [],
"noEngineReferences": false

}
As you can see I made an Assembly definition in my Scripts Folder and attached it to the Assembly Definition References from the Test Runner Assembly Definition Asset because I thought that might fix the problem.

But the Button in Test Runner for creating Test Scripts the proper way is still greyed out.

I tested everything in older versions (22LTS) and had no problem at all creating a Play Mode Test. Also, the .asmdef File looks very different in older Versions
{
"name": "Tests",
"optionalUnityReferences": [
    "TestAssemblies"
]

}
Has someone faced this type of issue? What am I doing wrong?
